# Simple query to perform joining operation

Tags: php, mysql

I am performing MySQL functions using PHP for my webpages.

I have got a table

```
table name -> users

 uname     oname
  john      alex
  john      murray
  john      joseph
  john      ray
```

and another table

```
table name -> more_info

fname    lname         more
 alex     some name   some info
 murray     //           //
 joseph     //           //
 ray       //            //
```

What I am trying to do is to run a query

Retrieve all the `oname` column values which are matched with `uname` john

This statement successfully retrieves the oname column values if uname = john

```
SELECT oname FROM users WHERE uname = 'john '
```

Now I want a statement something like this, based on the previously retrieved oname column values

```
SELECT * FROM more_info WHERE fname=oname // previos ones
```

I guess its `Join` or`innerJoin` but somehow I am unable to get the correct syntax of it or any other simple query to do this.

**My approach**

I thought to retrieve the oname column values first and then inside a for loop, based on number of rows returned run a query for each column, but this approach eats up my server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this query,

```
 SELECT * FROM `more_info` `i` INNER JOIN `users` `u` ON `i`.`fname`=`u`.`oname` WHERE `u`.`uname`="john"
```

Comment: +1 but however you made a mistake its i.fname = u.oname change it ! Thanks for your help

Comment: Oh my mistake...anyway glad i could help

Answer (score 1):

You can merge your two queries into one by a simple `INNER JOIN`

```
SELECT * FROM more_info mi
INNER JOIN users u ON mi.fname = u.oname
WHERE u.uname = 'john'
```

If there is some chance of null values in `more_info` table, then you should use `LEFT JOIN` instead of `INNER JOIN`. Otherwise it is not necessary.

Comment: +1 thanks but could you explain how does it work when you dont use the where clause as sherin jose used in his answer.

Comment: oh, sorry. if you want for a particular user's info, then you have to add a where clause. I thought this is for all users. My mistake. I'm updating my answer. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think the following query wll help u.

```
SELECT * FROM `more_info` WHERE `fname` = (SELECT `oname` FROM `users` WHERE `uname` = "john")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM users  A
INNER JOIN more_info B
    ON A.oname = B.fname
WHERE uname = 'john'
```

See [the MySQL documentation on the JOIN syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html) for details.

Comment: I think he need the data from more_info

Comment: @Sherin: And with `SELECT *` he gets them.